# Gauss divergence theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, integration, vector-fields, mathematics, calculus

I was reading new edition of Arfeken's book on Mathematical Physics I came to a two line state in the new edition in gauss divergence theorem section which was not included in the old edition and I didn't understand this new statement.

I am attaching an image of that part of the book, I underlined the exact statement, please help.

[image: 1]

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this is hard to understand is that it is *not true*. Consider Gauss law $\nabla \cdot D=\rho$ with a non-zero total charge $Q$ located near the origin. Then
$$
Q= \lim_{R\to \infty} \left(\int_{|{\bf r}|<R } \nabla \cdot {\bf D}\, d^3r\right)= \lim_{R\to \infty}\left(\int_{r=R} {\bf D}\cdot d{\bf S}\right),
$$
so the volume integral converges but the surface integral does not vanish.

Comment: Even i was feeling it incorrect too.Thanks for your confirmation, but really I am.very much disappointed that the book of higher reputation in physics community is conceptually incorrect.6th edition of that book when only arfken and Weber was there was the best and it doesn't contain that rubbish statement,involvement of Weber ruined it.As we are going forward in time people are ruining the best classical text in the name of update.

Comment: *involvement of Harris in 7th edition ruined it

Comment: @AyushArora a correct statement (if you're interested) is: "if $\mathbf{A}$ is a $C^1$ vector field which is compactly supported (i.e there is some ball $B_R$ of radius $R$ outside of which the vector field $\mathbf{A}$ vanishes), then all integrals over $\Bbb{R}^3$ converge and $\int_{\Bbb{R}^3}\text{div}(\mathbf{A})\,dV = 0$". (Proof by divergence thm.) As shown by mike stone's answer, simply assuming the volume integral converges is not good enough, because this only restricts growth of $\text{div}(\mathbf{A})$, but we also need control of the growth of the actual vector field $\mathbf{A}$.